# MySQL : Update Table upon certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have 2 tables , master and current table( refreshed very hr).
Both the table shave same structure:

Chk | description |state | date

I need to update / append ( add the new row ) into the master table if :

1) rows that have new IDs or

2) if a particular variable ( 'state' in this case) has changed. I tried to do it using below without success :

```
INSERT  into AGILE_TICKETS_DLY 
SELECT * FROM CURR_AGILE_TICKETS curr
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AGILE_TICKETS_DLY mstr
          WHERE (curr.chk != mstr.chk) OR ( curr.chk = mstr.chk and 
    mstr.state != curr.state))
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this ?

Comment: a trigger is probably what you need

Comment: Thanks but even in the trigger I am assuming I have to give the where condition correctly , I believe whatever I have here isnt detecting the change.. Can someone tell what is wrong in the WHERE condition ?

Comment: you have `mstr.state = curr.state` instead of `mstr.state != curr.state` probably

Comment: Try this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: There will be rows with new IDs as well so if I use on duplicate key then I cant capture that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this pair of queries:

```
-- insert new rows
insert into agile_tickets_dly
select * from curr_agile_tickets 
where chk not in (select chk from agile_tickets_dly);

-- update updated rows
update agile_tickets_dly x
join 
(
    select b.chk chk,b.description description,b.state state,b.date date 
    from agile_tickets_dly a, curr_agile_tickets b
    where 
        a.chk=b.chk and
        (a.description != b.description or a.state != b.state or a.date != b.date)
) y
on x.chk=y.chk
set x.description = y.description, x.state= y.state, x.date = y.date;
```

**Illustration:**

```
select * from agile_tickets_dly;
+------+-------------+---------+------------+
| chk  | description | state   | date       |
+------+-------------+---------+------------+
| 0    | desc-0      | state-1 | 01-01-2017 |
| 1    | desc-1      | state-1 | 01-01-2018 |
| 2    | desc-2      | state-2 | 01-02-2018 |
| 3    | desc-3      | state-3 | 01-03-2018 |
+------+-------------+---------+------------+

-- one new row with chk=4, three updated rows with chk=1,2,3
select * from curr_agile_tickets;
+------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
| chk  | description    | state           | date           |
+------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
| 0    | desc-0         | state-1         | 01-01-2017     |
| 1    | desc-1         | state-1         | date-1-updated |
| 2    | desc-2-updated | state-2         | 01-02-2018     |
| 3    | desc-3         | state-3-updated | 01-03-2018     |
| 4    | desc-4         | state-4         | 01-04-2018     |
+------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+

-- after executing the two queries
select * from agile_tickets_dly;
+------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
| chk  | description    | state           | date           |
+------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
| 0    | desc-0         | state-1         | 01-01-2017     |
| 1    | desc-1         | state-1         | date-1-updated |
| 2    | desc-2-updated | state-2         | 01-02-2018     |
| 3    | desc-3         | state-3-updated | 01-03-2018     |
| 4    | desc-4         | state-4         | 01-04-2018     |
+------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this in 2 separate steps:

1) First I append all new rows with IDs : this worked

```
INSERT  into AGILE_TICKETS_DLY 
 SELECT * FROM CURR_AGILE_TICKETS curr
  WHERE not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AGILE_TICKETS_DLY mstr
          WHERE (curr.chk = mstr.chk));
```

But then, I tried to do below got an error

2) Then replace the 'State' variable with new value:

```
 INSERT  into AGILE_TICKETS_DLY_1 (state)
SELECT state 
  from CURR_AGILE_TICKETS_1 curr
where exists ( select * from AGILE_TICKETS_DLY_1 mstr where curr.chk = 
       mstr.chk);
```

But this gives me an error :

SQL Error (1364) : Field 'chk' doesn't have a default value.

What does that mean ?